# input.files[0] returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send an image to a server but I always get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Here is my code:
**HTML**

```
<form id="form1">
    <input id="image" name="image" type="file"/>
    <input id="btnSave" name='btnSave' type="button" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
  $('#btnSave').click(function() {
    var fd = new FormData();    
    fd.append( 'file', $("#image").files[0] );
    $.ajax({
        url: 'img.php',
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert(data);              
        }
    });  
}
```

I have tested similar forms with the same image that I am using to test this code, also I don't want to submit the form yet with this code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A jQuery object does not have the `files` collection. You need to access the underlying `input` element like this:

```
fd.append('file', $("#image")[0].files[0]);
```

That said, I'd suggest changing the button to a `type="submit"` and hooking the handler to the `submit` event of the `form`. Then you can just pass the `form` element to the `FormData` constructor, like this:

```
<form id="form1">
  <input id="image" name="image" type="file"/>
  <input id="btnSave" name='btnSave' type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

```js
$('#form1').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'img.php',
    data: new FormData(this),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert(data);              
    }
  });  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will run the proper tests

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I   ran the  test and it works